# Tour of Go Exercise #23: my word counter doesn't work

Tags: go

I'm trying to resolve the puzzle from [go tour #23](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/23) and I don't understand why my word counter doesn't work. `print` seems to print the expected value but the tests sees only `1` regardless the count.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "unicode/utf8"

    "golang.org/x/tour/wc"
)

func WordCount(s string) map[string]int {
    // explode the string into a slice without whitespaces
    ws := strings.Fields(s)
    //make a new map
    c := make(map[string]int)
    //iterate over each word
    for _, v := range ws {
        c[v] = utf8.RuneCountInString(v)
    }

    print(c["am"])

    return c
}

func main() {
    wc.Test(WordCount)
}
```

The playground is available [here](https://play.golang.org/p/XSLKigwsEAp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're solving the wrong problem. It doesn't ask you for the length of each word, but for the number of times each word occurs. Change

```
c[v] = utf8.RuneCountInString(v)
```

for

```
c[v] += 1 // or c[v]++
```

Comment: You are right, though I don't understand c[v] += 1 ... I solved it with c[v] = strings.Count(s, v)

Comment: You are visiting each word. You keep a counter for each one of them in `c`. Each time you visit a word, you add 1 to its counter in `c`. If you visit the same word more than once, you will add 1 more than once. That is what `c[v] += 1` does. `strings.Count` also works, but it's wasteful, because you're doing a double loop (one inside `string.Count`) and also counting repeated words several times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `c[v] = utf8.RuneCountInString(v)`. It has two problems:

1. You're resetting the counter for each word every time you re-encounter it. You should increment, not set.
2. You are setting the number of runes in the word to the counter. The puzzle is "how many times a word appears in the text". so just do something like `c[v] = c[v] + 1` (if the entry is empty it will default to 0)

Also, I'd normalize the text - strip punctuation marks and lowercase everything.